# Align button to the left side near ChartContainer default Icons

Tags: sapui5

I have button (called BUTTON LEFT) in the sap.suite.ui.commons.ChartContainer:

```
<ChartContainer
    id="chartContainer"
    showFullScreen="true"   
    autoAdjustHeight="true">

    <dimensionSelectors>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:Button id="idButton" text="BUTTON LEFT"/>
    </dimensionSelectors> 

    <content>
        <ChartContainerContent
            icon = "sap-icon://line-chart"
            title = "Line Chart">

            <content>
                <viz:VizFrame id="chartContainerVizFrame" height="700px" width="100%" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}"></viz:VizFrame>
            </content>
        </ChartContainerContent>
    </content>
</ChartContainer>
```

I need to align this button to the left side near ChartContainer legend icon. Now it looks like:

[image]

But I would like to get something like this:

[image]

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/tfC43wxGkw2M9XqrkCpv?p=preview) is working example, feel free to edit it.

I am looking for the solution which will be inside in the sap.suite.ui.commons.ChartContainer. I do not want to use css for this if possible. Also I can not use width property of ToolbalSpacer (e.g. width="100px"), because I need ToolbalSpacer changing width when the screen resolution is changed. I know that I can change ToolbarSpacer according to screen resolution but I would like to not use this approach.

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <dimensionSelectors>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
       <m:Button id="idButton" text="BUTTON LEFT" />
  </dimensionSelectors>
```

**This is the least thing I could do for this situation.**

Comment: Thank you, I upvoted your answer. I also tried this solution before opening this issue, but I did not put so many ToolbarSpacer as you did. But there is still one ToolbarSpacer left which mentioned @Stephen S in the other answer. Your working proposal is here https://plnkr.co/edit/euKMOd5O9S6xLpfMXdtG?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

The ChartContainer control adds a ToolbarSpacer before the Chart controls(Personalization, Zoom, Fullscreen ..). This ToolbarSpacer comes between the Chart controls & the dimension Selectors. If you hide this spacer you could align you Button control next to the other control. Here is one way to do it

```
onAfterRendering : function() {
  oChart = this.getView().byId("chartContainer");
  oChart.getToolbar().getContent()[2].setVisible(false);
}
```

Since you have one Toolbarspacer & a Button, the additional Spacer will be the third control in the ToolBar content.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your answer. I tried it, it works, but when I switch on and off fullscreen button it is again not algined on the left side. The setVisible property is probably set back to true, or maybe all component is rendered again, I do not know what is going on. Please, have a look https://plnkr.co/edit/JYTPSnX5T3GqX6nqE9sZ?p=preview